# Alphabetical search not working in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have tried alphabetical search using below code but its not working, I don't see any error so please help

```
 if($("#newuser").length != 0) {
         var oTable = $("#newuser").DataTable({

        "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,

            "ajax": {
                "url": base_url+'users/listing',

                "type": "POST",
              },


            dom: 'Alfrtip',
                  alphabetSearch: {
                         column: 2
                  },    
            initComplete: function( settings, json ){
                         this.api().alphabetSearch().draw();      
                  },     
            "columnDefs": [{ orderable: true, targets: [0]  }],
            "order": [[6, "desc" ]],
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Alfrtip',
    alphabetSearch: {
      column: 0
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.7/css/dataTables.alphabetSearch.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.7/js/dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**You can learn more** [clickhere](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-alphabetsearch/)